# How to debug php/MySQL COUNT(id) returning 1 instead of total entries value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pagination

I need the total number of entries in my database.

Question: Why does the line "print_r($rows)" return "Array ( [COUNT(id)] => 79 )" but then the line "$recordCount = Count($row); echo "
 record count = " . $recordCount;" returns "record count = 1".

I've tried a massive amount of different versions of this code, but I cant type them all here or it would take forever to read. Here is the current version of the code, which is giving me the unexpected results I mention above:

```
// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $startRow, $rowsPerPage";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM games";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);
$recordCount = Count($row);
echo "<br/> record count = " . $recordCount;



$totalPages = ceil($recordCount / $rowsPerPage);
$pagination = "<div class='pagination'>";

for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
  $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
  echo 'wtf!';
}

$pagination .= "</div>";
echo ' <br/> pagination = ' . $pagination;
```

THANKS TO YOU HEROES I NOW HAVE IT CORRECT: Here incase someone else in 2018 is reading online and finding lots of incorrect implementations of it:

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as countid FROM games";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();

$recordCount = $row["countid"]; // the countid gives me the total i expected :DDDD
echo "<br/> record count = " . $recordCount;
```

Comment: Post the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE games`

Comment: `Count($row)` is the number of rows returned - not the content of the rows, try `echo $row["COUNT(id)"];`

Comment: The `$row` is an array that only contains 1 values which is `[COUNT(id)] => 79`. I would suggest you change your query to something like `SELECT COUNT(id) total_games FROM games` and then access the result using `echo $row['total_games'];`

Comment: using a alias in the query is eazier.. `COUNT(id) as id_count` and use `$row['id_count']` in PHP.. Using `$row["COUNT(id)"];` is a bit tricky in PHP @NigelRen

Comment: ah ok i think i understand :DD  ... also I did try using the alias thing, but said something like "invalid index for array" when i ran it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553990/number-of-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row` is an associative array with an entry for every column in the result set. Since there's only one column there, `count($row)` returns `1`. Instead, you should just access the only column there:

```
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
$recordCount = $row["COUNT(id)"];
```

Comment: amazing man thank you. I've been fiddling around beating around that bush for ages and I almost had it. As a sidenote this answer is slightly wrong. I will adjust my question to show th eanswer and mark yours correct as this and the other commenters above is what made me find the correct answer

Comment: i believe it should be `COUNT(id)` it matters how it's been used in the query.. if the query is using `COUNT(id)` the PHP code should also use ``COUNT(id)``.. it's case sensitive

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, that's right. Momentary lapse of concentration - edited and fixed.

Comment: Well i wasn't completely 100% sure but it looked logical to me.  Because i always use aliases in these situations when using MySQL functions i never used it like this,,

Comment: for me i couldnt get it working , without using the alias technique and passing that as the index to $row[]; --but you still solved all my confusion with this answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could either aliase the column so that you can then use it as a key in associative array or since you already know that this statement:

```
1.$results = $conn->query($sql); looks something like this:
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|        13 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

2.$row = $results->fetch_assoc();returns an array with 1 element
```

So, you can just write $recordCount = $row[0]; to fetch that count.

The above answer is correct as well, but wanted to let you know about this direct, alternate approach in case you forget to aliase for whatever reason!

Comment: thanks for your help. I got it working but not sure I fully understood it all

Comment: Please let me know which part and I will be happy to explain further.

Comment: thank you for your time spent here. I have stopped working on web development for the time being and can't remember specifically which part i was stuck on the most. Hugely appreciate people such as yourself for offering the help tho. much love